# Check if PropertyGroup item is set to a value in .csproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, static-code-analysis

I am using `.targets` files to include common functionality in .csproj files.

In the target file, I want to check if a property was already set before, and if yes, do not set it again.

I need this because I am using the specific target file in many solutions, and I want to include the custum Property only if it wasn't set before.

The property I am talking about is

`<PropertyGroup>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(SolutionDir)CustomizedAllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>`

If this ruleset was specified before Importing the target file, I don't want to include it again in the `.targets` file.

How do I check in .csproj if the `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>...</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` was set before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern I've seen most often is to set it conditionally based on comparing it to an empty value:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet Condition="'$(CodeAnalysisRuleSet)' == ''">$(SolutionDir)CustomizedAllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[Edit: responding to comment with code example]

Here's a longer example that works for me:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PropertyValue Condition="$(PropertyValue) == ''">Default value</PropertyValue>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="$(PropertyValue)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Gives the console output:

```
Project "D:\temp\test.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  Default value
Done Building Project "D:\temp\test.proj" (default targets).
```

Comment: This condition seems to work only when `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet></CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` was included before with an empty string inside, but not when `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` is not present at all before.

Comment: @PinteDani MSBuild should treat any previously undeclared variable as an empty value.  Can you give more details about how it's not working for you?  See the example in my edit.

Comment: Thanks to your further explanation, I saw in the console output that msbuild is including some default `MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset` behind the scenes, that's why I didn't got an empty string as I thought. I will accept your answer since this does correctly check if a value is set.